# stop the loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, quotes

I'm new to javascript. I have found this script http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/ for text slideshow, I love it!

```js
(function() {
    
  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">third quote</h2>
```

But how can I set loop to false?
I have 5 quotes, and after the slide I want to show the last quote fixed

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you mean you have 5 quotes and after showing these five you need to show an another fixed quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a look to [the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aforni/2ra4krq1/1/):

```
  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;

    var $el = quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000);

    if ((quoteIndex % quotes.length) < (quotes.length - 1)) {
      $el.fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }
  }

  showNextQuote();
```

What you have to do is to split the statement:

```
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
```

in two parts. The first part which control the fade in of the element:

```
var $el = quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000);
```

The second part which checks to fade out or not that element:

```
if ((quoteIndex % quotes.length) < (quotes.length - 1)) {
  $el.fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}
```

Comment: why keeping the modulus `quoteIndex % quotes.length`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by add a condition before this line:

```
quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
```

add this:

```
if(quoteIndex == quotes.length - 1)
{
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000);
}
```

This should do the trick.

**Edit:** sorry!! forgot the last quote part.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {

var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;

function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    if(quoteIndex < quotes.length -1) {
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
        
    }
    else if(quoteIndex < quotes.length) {
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length).fadeIn(2000);
    }
}

showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">3rd quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">4th quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">5th quote</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the Five quotes in a row, you can try this.

```
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
    var quoteslength = quotes.length;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        if(quoteIndex < quoteslength){
           quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
         }
    }
    showNextQuote();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

detect the last one, and stop repeating the call to itself

```js
(function() {
    
  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    if (quoteIndex == quotes.length - 1) {
      // it is our last one
      quotes.eq(quoteIndex).fadeIn(2000)
      // we won't get invoked any more
    }
    else {
      quotes.eq(quoteIndex) // no longer need for the modulus, since we wont go beyond length
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">third quote</h2>
```